# TP-LINK TL-WN823N - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, usb

My TP-Link TL-WN823N V2 is working in Ubuntu 16.04 with the driver provided by ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu, but I need to unplug and replug the dongle at each boot to activate it.

Is something I can do to make it activate on boot?

Thanks in advance.

---

@Pilot6 Thanks for the reply. Had trouble posting this in the comments, and wasn't sure where to put it. So put it here. Here is lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1058:25e2 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:5031 Seagate RSS LLC FreeAgent GoFlex USB 3.0
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0109  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is the uname -a:

```
Linux PC 4.4.0-93-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Can you post output of `lsusb` and `uname -a` ?

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for the reply. Put info in edited question above.

Comment: @HoChiChi for future reference, including such requested information in the question is indeed the correct way to do it.